# Is the word “organization”a synecdoche?

Tags: meaning

I’m interested in learning the proper term for an entity made up of people—members. Eg an organization is a concept, but is there another word for the whole being more than the sum of its parts?

Comment: Can you be clearer what the actual question is? Do you want to know if organization is a synecdoche (please provide a context/example)? Do you want a general term for a group of people working together, and don't like organization for some reason? Or do you want a word specifically for something that's more than the sum of its parts? Can you provide an example sentence if you're looking for a particular word.

Comment: It may be that you're confusing synecdoche (using part for the whole, or whole for the part: 'the admiral commanded 250 sail'; 'the train's boiler needs repairing' – rhetorical sleight of hand) with hypernymy/hyponymy (cutlery = knives / forks / spoons / ... // furniture = chairs / tables / bureaus / chiffoniers / ...).

Comment: An organization is a group of people. I don't think there's a single word that adds the concept that the whole is more than just the sum of its parts.

Comment: Is that not addressed at, eg, https://www.google.com/search?q=synecdoche%3F&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB1057GB1057&oq=synecdoche%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j69i61.1723j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8